# R: Aggregate data but some aggregated observations need to be split up

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, aggregate, plyr

I have two data frames that I need to merge. A made up example of each is below. These are school districts: the first would be revenues, the second is grades.

---

```
School district     revenue
Richland 1          8702
Richland 2          3749
Richland Board       892
Charleston          6324
Greenville          1245
Greenville Board     371
```

---

```
School district     grade
Richland 1          A
Richland 2          A+
Charleston          B
Greenville          D
```

The objective is to merge these two data frames and have the final result be aggregated to the same level as the second (grade) data frame. I've had to do a data dictionary to merge them because the names are different in each (though I removed that to simplify here) but also to handle the aggregation. What I plan to do is set up my dictionary in the following way:

```
School_dist1    School_dist2
Richland 1      Richland 1
Richland 2      Richland 2
?????           Richland Board
Charleston      Charleston
Greenville      Greenville
Greenville      Greenville Board
```

Then I would simply aggregate on the school_dist1 column. As you can see though, the problem is that while Greenville Board can simply be aggregated into Greenville, the Richland Board needs to be split (evenly) across the two Richland Boards.

I tried searching for a solution using every possible keyword I could think of but couldn't find anything due to the weird nature of the problem. The gist of it is, I need to aggregate data but some of the observations need to be split and then shared across other observations to which they're being aggregated.

Is there any way to do this? Am I making any sense? I'm completely stumped on this one.

Comment: would be helpful if you showed the code of your attempts

Comment: I genuinely have no idea where to begin. I don't even know if this is something that is possible which is why I'm here. I can normally just search here and figure it out on the way but I couldn't find anyone asking how to do anything similar to this.

Comment: It sounds like you might need to use one of the joining functions in the `dplyr` package.  What you may want is called a `full_join`. There is an excellent description here: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html#introduction-7

Answer (score 2):

This is the long way home, but it will get you there...

```
# your data, dont use spaces in column names
df1 <- read.table(text = "School_district     revenue
Richland_1          8702
                 Richland_2          3749
                 Richland_Board       892
                 Charleston          6324
                 Greenville          1245
                 Greenville_Board     371", header = T)

df2 <- read.table(text = "School_district     grade
Richland_1          A
Richland_2          A+
Charleston          B
Greenville          D", header = T)

library(tidyverse)
# split df1 with boards and non-boards into separate dfs
boards <- dplyr::filter(df1, grepl("Board", df1$School_district)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(School_district = gsub("_Board", "", School_district))
df1 <-  dplyr::filter(df1, !grepl("Board", df1$School_district))

# look up how many times a certain school district appears in df1
boards$num_splits <- map_int(boards$School_district,
                             ~ grep(., df1$School_district) %>% length)
# add new column for revenue divided by number of appearances
boards <- transmute(boards,
                    match_name = School_district,
                    add_value = revenue / num_splits)

# if I knew how to use fuzzy_join you could probably drop this part
df1$match_name <- gsub("_.*", "", df1$School_district)

full_join(df1, boards) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(new_revenue = sum(revenue, add_value, na.rm = T)) %>%
    select(-match_name) %>%
    full_join(df2)

# A tibble: 4 × 5
School_district revenue add_value new_revenue  grade
<chr>   <int>     <dbl>       <dbl> <fctr>
1      Richland_1    8702       446        9148      A
2      Richland_2    3749       446        4195     A+
3      Charleston    6324        NA        6324      B
4      Greenville    1245       371        1616      D
```